# Why can't qtcreator run this?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I compiled an UI app with Qtcreator but it cannot run it for some reason. The app crash seemingly before the main, giving me just assembler code in the debugger.
This only happens when launching the app through Qtcreator. It works fine when using command line. But that make it really hard to debug.

I looked around and people seem to say that could be caused by a faulty lib, so I guess the program may be linked differently when used with Qtcreator. How can I check that ? And how do I fix it ?

Comment: Include your compiling error. Also  make clean your project and rebuild.

Comment: There is no compiling error. The program compile with or without qtcreator and run well outside of qtcreator, but does not run inside

Comment: This is maybe an issue with your PATH. But usually this is in the opposite direction (works in QtCreator but not outside).
QtCreator adds the selected Qt libraries to its PATH environment so that your executable finds the Qt library even if not located beside them. 
If it crashes, it may mean that the PATH of QtCreator contains a version of Qt (or another lib) that is not compatible with you exe. This is weird but not impossible.
You can try to check the PATH of QtCreator and compare with the PATH of Windows, or exchange them to try to confirm this assumption or not.

Comment: Does it do this with just this app, or any app you create inside Creator? Knowing this might isolate the problem, either to a PATH variable or something in your project file (assuming you're using qmake).